# Determine if menu link is current/active

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

When rendering a menu, in the twig file, you can set a class if `item.in_active_trail` is set:

```
  {% for item in items %}
    {%
      set classes = [
        item.in_active_trail ? 'is-active',
      ]
    %}
```

However this class is applied to each link in the trail - so if you are on the third level, three links get this class.

Is there anything I can see OOTB on `item` or add to it if the menu link is the current page? I need to highlight it and not just items in the trail itself.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to combine it with `item.below`? I suppose (not tested) that this could be used to only apply the class to the deepest item within the active trail. The code could look something like this:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item.in_active_trail and not item.below %}
    set classes = [
       'is-active',
    ]
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Well, that would _almost_ work - but I am using Menu Block and all children are always expanded. I am showing a two-level tree in the left sidebar.

Comment: Again I have not tried it, but `below` is not the same as `is_expanded`, so I thought it might have worked...

Comment: Have tested this and it didn't work for me.

```
{% if item.in_active_trail and not item.below %}
  set link_classes = [
     'testing',
  ]
{% endif %}
{{ link(item.title, item.url, create_attribute().addClass(link_classes)) }}
```